# Converting two arrays into an array of objects PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I am currently building a database that stores recipes, so I have a table for recipes, a table for ingredients, and a pivot table to link them as a many-to-many relationship. Inside this pivot table, I am storing quantities and will want to add units too for each ingredient.

Current when I return my data it is in the following format:

```
{
    "recipe_id": 1,
    "recipe_name": "non",
    "ingredients": [
        "aut"
        "expedita",
        "non",
        "quod",
        "id"
    ],
    "quantities": [
        "3.00",
        "3.00",
        "3.00",
        "3.00",
        "3.00"
    ],
    "method": "Instructions go here",
    "updated_at": "17 hours ago"
},
```

However, when I come to display this I will want to have the ingredient at index 0 displayed alongside the quantity at index 0, the same for 1, 2, 3, etc. My initial thoughts are that it would be best to store this data as an array of objects with keys so that ingredient index 0 becomes its own object with a name and a quantity. e.g.

```
"ingredients": [
    "1": {
        "name": "aut",
        "quantity": "3.00"
    }
],
```

What I am not sure about is should I do this before I return the data? Or should I just keep it like it is and do this combination of data when I need to display it?
And how would I go about doing this combination?
Or have I simply got my tables arranged incorrectly to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like your database tables are OK, although without actually seeing them this is hard to say. I do however wonder how you ended up with the data result you have, that's not a normal result of a database query.

Comment: You have two arrays here, assuming that the order in both is correct, all you need is to iterate first with `foreach($arr1 as $key => $val)`, find qty by `$key` in `$arr2` and built associative array(s) `$arr3` with a combination of these data. At the end json_encode that array to get JSON object.

Comment: I am not sure if it was you, but another user already posted the same thing like 5 days ago... Did you create a new username ?